# Centering a Horizontal Scrolling Cards Bootstrap4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Trying to make a Single Row of Horizontal Scrolling Cards but facing  issue of centering the div.

Tried using
a) mx-auto class
b) text-align: center

Nothing seems to be working and i am getting lot of space on right side on desktop view.

However in mobile screens the scrolling div is neatly centered.

Appreciate esteemed experts to point me in the right direction.

[image: doesn't center on desktop screen!]

[image: working fine on mobile screen]

```css
<style>
      
img {
  border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.forlabel {
    margin-top:-12px;
}
.forlabeldiv {
    border:solid; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-radius:5px;  
    <!-- margin-left:5px; 
    margin-right:5px; 
    margin-bottom:15px;-->
    margin: 0,auto;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
.forlabelspan { 
        color: #0275d8;
        background:white;
        font-size:14px;
        font-weight:800;
}       
.btn {
    width:30%;
    text-align: center
    margin-bottom:5px   
    }
.card-block {
    min-height: 25vh;
    margin-bottom:15px;
}   
    
.profile, .card {
    background:#ced7df!important;
    text-align:center;
    }
    
.master {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0,auto;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Single Row Horizontal Scrolling Cards</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">   

    
    
</head> 
<body>
<!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->
<h2>Single Row Horizontal Scrolling Cards</h2>  
<div class="container-fluid p-3 m-3 master" >   
  <div class="container forlabeldiv row  max-auto" >    
     <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 forlabel" >
       <span class=" forlabelspan">Expert Panel</span> 
    </label> 
    
    <div class="row flex-nowrap overflow-auto ">

       <div class="col-12 col-lg-6" >
            <div class="card card-block profile" >      
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/100/09f/fff.png" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>     
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>    
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>    
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>    
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>  
          <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
            <div class="card card-block  " style="text-align: center" >     
            <img class="mx-auto" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="100" height="100" >
             First Name Last Name<br>
             Title of Person<br>
             Credentials of Person<br>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger mx-auto">BOOK</a> 
           </div>
        </div>  
        
        </div> <!--*** end of row flex  *** -->
       </div> <!--*** end of label div  *** -->
    </div> <!--*** end of container-flex -->
    
<!----------------------xxxxxxx---------------------------->    
</body> 

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-STof4xm1wgkfm7heWqFJVn58Hm3EtS31XFaagaa8VMReCXAkQnJZ+jEy8PCC/iT18dFy95WcExNHFTqLyp72eQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>  
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Added a CSS body tag with padding and the div got centered:

```
body { padding:50px; }
```

Not sure what it did , but it fixed my issue!